# summarize() equivalent in SQL (creating a summary table in SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to create a summary table.
For example, the dataset `df` looks like this:

```
type   category   color
bmw    a          black
bmw    b          black
bmw    c          white 
bmw    d          black 
bmw    e          white 
.....
```

Basically, `type` will be the same value throughout the whole dataset, and `category` will be all unique values. What I want to do is to figure out the proportion of the colors. So I hope to get an output that looks something like this:

```
color   count   prop
black   48      0.34 
white   62      0.52
grey    20      ...
.....
```

Please note that the numbers and proportions above are all made up, not proportional, just for illustration purposes.

In R, all I have to do is use `dplyr` and use the `summarise` function to output the desired result, but not sure how to do it in SQL.

I've tried doing the following code:

```
SELECT type, category, color, count(*) 
FROM df
```

However it gave me an error.

Comment: @DaleK I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select color, count(*),
       count(*) * 1.0 / sum(count(*)) over ()
from df
group by color;
```

Comment: what does over () do in this case?

Comment: @TheImpaler thank you, now I got it.